# OpenCV G-API findContours: pass result to kernel?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

OpenCV G-API defines `gapi::findCountours` result as `GArray<GArray<Point>>`. Fair enough. So, how do I pass this to a kernel? G-API only unpacks the outer most `GArray` translating it to `std::vector`. How do I make it unpack the `GArray` in the next level of the template, so I can get the desired `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to unpack `GArray<GArray<Point>>` manually.

If you want to pass that to a custom kernel, it has to take `GArray<GArray<Point>>` as input.

If unpacking of complex G-types doesn't happen by itself, it can be a bug. Recently you could have faced such one if you had tried to write a custom kernel with `GArray<GArray<Point>>` as input. Now it's fixed in OpenCV v4.5.2, and all thanks to you!
PRs merged: [Fix kernel's input conversion bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19815), [Fix bug of GArray passing through a graph](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19828).